# Issue when creating an expanding search bar using :focus-within

Tags: html, css

I want to make a search bar as this website's search bar: https://www.arrivalguides.com/en.

I tried with this code: ([Here's a codepen](https://codepen.io/Thanushi/pen/NWjwvdg))

HTML:

```html
<div class="col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-end all-buttons">
  <div class="col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-end search-bar">
    <a  nbButton  outline class="text-decoration-none add-btn" id="add-btn-hide" >
      <i class="nb-plus fa-1x"> </i> Add User
    </a>

    <button nbButton class=" multi-delete-btn" id="delete-btn-hide" >
      <i class="nb-trash fa-2x"></i>
      Delete All
    </button>

    <input type="text" class="search-input" id="search-input" fullWidth nbInput placeholder="Enter Search" (keyup)="onKey($event)" />
    <button nbButton class="search-btn" nbTooltip="Quick Search " nbTooltipPlacement="top" status="primary">
<!--       <nb-icon icon="search-outline"></nb-icon> -->icon
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
body{
  margin:40px;
}

.all-buttons {
  height: 30px;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.info-btn {
  padding: 0.4rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  margin-right: 3px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-color: blue;
}

.advanced-filters {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 0.6rem 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin-left: 1px;
}

.multi-delete-btn {
  margin: 0 8px 0 3px;
  color:white;
  background-color: orange;
  border-color:orange;
  border-radius: 0.25rem ;
  padding: 0 5px 0 0 ;
  opacity: 1 !important;
   transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
}
.add-btn {
  border-color:blue ;
  background-color: blue ;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  margin: 0 ;
  opacity: 1 !important;
   transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
}
.search-bar {
  border: none !important;
  margin-right: 2px !important;
  border-radius: 100px ;
  min-width: 33px !important;
  position: relative;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
}
.search-input {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
  opacity: 0;
  width:40px !important;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-out;

  &:focus {
    outline: 0;
    
  }
}
.search-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 0.25rem !important;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 0 !important;
  position: absolute ;
  top:0 ;
  bottom:0;
  right: 0;
}

.search-bar:focus-within{
  width:50% !important;
  border: 2px solid brown !important;

  .search-input{
    width: 100% !important ;
    background-color: rgba(196, 158, 233, 0.205);
    color: black !important;
    cursor: initial ;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .add-btn{
   display: none !important;

  }
  .multi-delete-btn{
   display: none!important;

  }
}
```

The issue:
When I click outside of the search icon, the "Add" button and "Delete-all" button should appear. But in my case they are just moving. (When I click the search icon, the add-button and delete-all button disappear– this is okay)

Comment: My codepen link:   https://codepen.io/Thanushi/pen/NWjwvdg?editors=1100

Comment: is ur codepen working? U Got ur answer?

Comment: @Amalnandan It is working when i click search icon. Did You notice When clicking out side of the icon ( to get initial state) add button and delete button are just moving.  I need like https://www.arrivalguides.com/en.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach isolating only the search input and a search input container. The input is absolutely positioned inside a relative container so that I could grow the input from right to left. I did this by anchoring it to the right side of the parent container using `right: 0`.

I'm combining `focus-within` and `placeholder-shown` to grow/shrink the `input`. Using `placeholder-shown` is needed to prevent the input from shrinking if the user has typed something in the input. To hide the placeholder text and only show the search icon when the input is shrunk, I'm making the placeholder text color `transparent`.

```css
.search-input-container {
  position: relative;
}

.search-input {
  --search-icon-width: 24px;
  --search-max-width-expanded: 20rem;
  --search-max-width-collapsed: 2.3rem;
  --search-color: #ccc;
  background-color: var(--search-color);
  max-width: var(--search-max-width-collapsed);
  padding: .5rem 0.75rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.3s max-width, 0.3s margin;
  border: none;
  background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/93/93642.png);
  background-size: 18px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: calc(100% - 10px) 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.search-input:focus-within,
.search-input:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  max-width: var(--search-max-width-expanded);
  padding-right: var(--search-icon-width);
}

.search-input:not(:focus-within)::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}


/* Ignore */

body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-input-container">
  <input placeholder="search" type="search" class="search-input">
</div>
```

Comment: I have another two buttons too( Add and Delete buttons). I need to hide when click search icon. Again they should appear when i click out side iof the search bar.  My Question is How to hide those buttons as this website https://www.arrivalguides.com/en.

Comment: codepen.io/Thanushi/pen/NWjwvdg?editors=1100   See here.  Notice When click out side of the icon the buttons are just moving. NOT Appear/Disappear